# Dynamic x-axis on a real-time flot chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, real-time, flot

Is there a way to update the x-axis on a real time flot chart?

I want something like this -> (http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/realtime/index.html)
but as you can see, there are no values on the x-axis..

So, is there a way to shift the x-axis values as the chart shifts?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first need to show the x axis:

```
var plot = $.plot("#placeholder", [ getRandomData() ], {
    xaxis: {
        show: true
    }
});
```

Then on every data update you need to update the grid as well:

```
function update() {
    plot.setData([getRandomData()]);
    plot.setupGrid(); // updating the grid
    plot.draw();
    setTimeout(update, updateInterval);
}
```

Check [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2hgVTjYWoCGTwv9tANOT?p=info) for example.